# Exclude some posts from displaying in wordpress wp_query based on some condition

Tags: wordpress

I need some posts excludes from displaying in wp_query in some conditons. I use below code to do it, and the code works correctly, but I set the `posts_per_page` to `12` and by this code the skiped posts are counted , for example instead of `12` post in each page it has different post numbers (10,2,5 , ...)

```
while( $query->have_posts() ){ 
   $query->the_post();        

    if(condition)
    {
         //Show the post
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right posts_per_page will count these posts as they are part of the query. Can you cancel those posts on Query level? is it some meta or taxonomy value you are comparing? you may do that on query level and get posts only which match to your criteria.

Comment: @Mohsin Thanks. No I can not do this. The level is not meta or taxonomy.

Comment: In that case you might need to use own pagination rule, you may save all final posts (after skipping into an ARRAY) and then loop that array posts in equal number of posts per page once you have the final list of posts. So you have equal number of posts per page. In short you need to do skipping part before you do the pagination or division of posts per page so you get better control of number of posts per page...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change the query arguments to exclude posts instead of checking inside the query? For instance -

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);
if ( $condition ) {
    // meta query
    // date query
    // taxonomy query
    // or set other query arguments to exclude posts
} 
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Could please share your code so that we can understand clearly?